# Slickgrid: How to exclude checkboxSelectColumn from columnPicker

Tags: slickgrid

Is there an easy way to exclude the column created by `Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn` from the column Picker?

With regular columns, you can include `excludeFromColumnPicker: true` in the column definition but that doesn't seem to work with the checkbox-column.

```js
var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn(
   { cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel", 
     excludeFromColumnPicker: true // this doesn't seem to work
   });
```

I also tried excluding the column before passing the column definition array to the columnPicker, like this:

```js
var columnPickerColumns = myColumns.filter(
   (column) => column.id !== "_checkbox_selector"
);

var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(
   columnPickerColumns,
   grid,
   options
);
```

When passing `columnPickerColumns`, the checkbox column is missing, but somehow the checkbox column still appears in the column picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the checkbox column gets created dynamically through the function `getColumnDefinition()` (shown below) which is inside `slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js` file at this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/e8abe341c75fd81abdef8b2994fa9f355fb60797/plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js#L325C14-L338) number

```js
function getColumnDefinition() {
      return {
        id: _options.columnId,
        name: (_options.hideSelectAllCheckbox || _options.hideInColumnTitleRow) ? "" : "<input id='header-selector" + _selectAll_UID + "' type='checkbox'><label for='header-selector" + _selectAll_UID + "'></label>",
        toolTip: (_options.hideSelectAllCheckbox || _options.hideInColumnTitleRow) ? "" : _options.toolTip,
        field: "sel",
        width: _options.width,
        resizable: false,
        sortable: false,
        cssClass: _options.cssClass,
        hideSelectAllCheckbox: _options.hideSelectAllCheckbox,
        formatter: checkboxSelectionFormatter
      };
    }
```

and it's basically missing any of the exclude flags in there. I think this could be a great contributions that you could make to the project by creating a new PR (pull request) and add all necessary flags.

Just for comparison, I have the same plugin in [Slickgrid-Universal](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal) and I added a few more flags as can be seen on this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/b3fbcf57556a7eb964782eb967c187f4307323f8/packages/common/src/extensions/slickCheckboxSelectColumn.ts#L203-L223)

```js
  getColumnDefinition(): Column {
    return {
      // ....
      excludeFromExport: true,
      excludeFromColumnPicker: true,
      excludeFromGridMenu: true,
      excludeFromQuery: true,
      excludeFromHeaderMenu: true,
  };
}
```

Again I would suggest you to make a contribution to the project since I'm not using it myself because I have my own plugins. Perhaps you could improve on that and make it as an option like you provided in your question (`excludeFromColumnPicker: _options.excludeFromColumnPicker || false`).

Also note that I'm a major collaborator to the project and we released v4.0 recently, which is removing jQuery, and are not supporting older versions (on [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) fork that is)

EDIT

The fix was pushed and released under the new SlickGrid [v4.0.1](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/releases/tag/4.0.1)

Comment: I just tried to make the PR but saw you've already done it. Thanks!